# Sacar elemento de una lista de objetos

Tags: java

Tengo una lista de objetos y tengo que sacar un elemento de ella.

```
 vlstZonas = zonaContr.getDatosZona(IdParticipante);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método devuelve una lista de objetos como la de la imagen.

He probado cosas como ésta:

```
 int zona = (Integer)vlstZonas.get(0).get(idZona);
 int zona = (Integer)vlstZonas.get(0).get(0);
 int Zona = (int) vlstZonas.getIdZona();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haz un forEach , este te sacará todos los objetos del array

```
int idZona;
        for (ZonaMayoristaPOJO objetoSacado : vlstZonas) {
            idZona = objetoSacado.getIdZona();
        }
```

Entiendo que ZonaMayoristaPOJO es el objeto que contiene esos atributos
Despues sería pillar los datos que quieras del objeto a traves de getters

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido

Comment: Pero haciendo esto vas machacando la `int idZona`

Comment: Cierto, sería mejor en vez de un int hacer un array de ints con un contador para el indice.asi sabes que están ordenados,no me había fijado

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo estas visualizando mal. Estás casteando a Integer un objeto de tipo ZonaMayoristaPOJO. Es decir, tú quieres acceder a idZona que es un integer, sería algo así:

```
int zona = ((ZonaMayoristaPOJO)vlstZonas[0]).getIdZona();
```